# How to quickly convert from items in a list of lists to list of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python

Assuming I have the following structure:

```
listoflist = [[0,1,2,3,4],[2,4,2,3,4],[3,4,5,None,3],...]
```

Assuming I have:

```
headers = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
```

I want to convert each to:

```
listofobj = [{"A":0,"B":2,"C":3,"D":4,"E":5},{"A":2,"B":4,"C":2,"E":4}]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Note that D: does not show up for the 3rd dictionary in the converted list because it is None. Am looking for the most optimal way/quickest performance for this.

Comment: What's `null`? Python doesn't have anything by that name.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to perform an operation on each element of a list, the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) builtin function to match each element of `headers` against the corresponding element in `listoflist`, and the [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict) builtin function to convert each of those into a dictionary. So, the code you want is

```
listofobj = [dict(zip(headers, sublist)) for sublist in listoflist]
```

Removing `None` values is probably best done in another function:

```
def without_none_values(d):
  return {k:d[k] for k in d if d[k] is not None}
```

With that function, we can complete the list with

```
listofobj = [without_none_values(dict(zip(headers, sublist))) for sublist in listoflist]
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy to do in Python >= 2.7 using dictionary comprehension:

```
listofobj = [
    { k: v for k, v in zip(headers, sublist) if v is not None } 
         for sublist in listoflist
]
```

In Python 2.6 one needs to use `dict`:

```
listofobj = [
    dict((k, v) for k, v in zip(headers, sublist) if v is not None)
         for sublist in listoflist
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate through each `list`, and `zip` it with the list of `headers`.

```
headers = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
listoflist = [[0,1,2,3,4],[2,4,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[0,9,7,6,5]]
[dict(zip(headers, sublist)) for sublist in listoflist]
```

Output

```
[{'A': 0, 'C': 2, 'B': 1, 'E': 4, 'D': 3},
 {'A': 2, 'C': 2, 'B': 4, 'E': 4, 'D': 3},
 {'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': 2, 'E': 4, 'D': 4},
 {'A': 5, 'C': 7, 'B': 6, 'E': 9, 'D': 8},
 {'A': 0, 'C': 7, 'B': 9, 'E': 5, 'D': 6}]
```

Answer (score 0):

`[x for x in l if x is not None]` keeps all values that are not `None`

We `enumerate` over `headers` and access the element at the corresponding index in each `sublist` of `listoflist` using `l[ind]`.

`if l[ind]` will be `True` if the value is not `None` so we use that element as a key or else ignore it if the value `is None`.

```
list_of_obj = [dict(zip([x for ind ,x in enumerate(headers) if l[ind] is not None],[x for x in l if x is not None])) for l in listoflist]
```

Comment: `filter(None, l)` doesn't do what you want. In particular, it will remove `0`s, and it won't match values with the right elements of `headers`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Pandas Series object from each of the lists in your listoflist, using headers as the index.
Then drop None values using dropna() method. And finally create a dictionary from each Series.

```
import pandas as pd
listofobj = [dict(pd.Series(x, index = headers).dropna()) for x in listoflist]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Code only answers are (sometimes) good, but code + explanation are (most times) better